# How to get all four monitors working?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have 4 monitors on my desktop setup:

1. ASUS z97-E/usb3.1
2. NVIDIA GTX 750 ti graphics card
3. Intel Core i5-4690

Two bottom monitors are hooked up to NVIDIA card.
Two top monitors hooked up to Intel dedicated graphics card.

[image]

When I first install Ubuntu I had all four monitors but it was terrible. There was alot of tearing on the NVIDIA displays which naturally I attributed to driver issues. So I installed the proprietary driver from NVIDIA.

The monitors are being recognized:

[image]

Just not displaying anything.

I know this has to be possible in 2016 with Ubuntu.

Somebody please help.

**EDIT 05/16/2016**

I managed to get all four monitors on using xrandr.

But it is mirroring one of the displays and they are not independent.

How do I fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of Google, trial and error and the help of others on this forum I was able to get all four monitors working relatively reliably. First off [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) was amazingly helpful

But it didn't quite get me all the way there. Instead of updating to nvidia-364 like the other question says I updated to nvidia-367 and rebooted.

After reboot all monitors were on but they were still not right. But I was then able to use xrandr to reposition the monitors in the correct place. The man page for xrandr is pretty good if you need help there.

Finally what I learned in the process: gnome3 seems to not handle the multi-monitor setup well at all. It would work until login and then fail nearly everytime and start to misbehave. Even after updating to latest drivers. Additionally, Xubuntu handled the multi-head setup reasonably well right out of the box. Its just not my favorite distro. Lastly, Ubuntu MATE seems to have been the easiest in terms of start to finish getting setup.

[image]